# MVC 4 SimpleMembership Using a Custom Schema With UserId Guid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

The default behavior out of the box for **SimpleMembership** is to have an **int** for the **UserId**.

Is there a quick way to have the SimpleMembership UserId **work with a GUID**?

If not could I extend the SimpleMembership to do so?

What would be the best way to go about this?

Has anyone had any success using the **MemFlex** open source library started by Scott Allen?

https://github.com/OdeToCode/Memflex

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to use an int at the moment, maybe it will be extended to use guids in future releases.

You can check out the source code of the "aspnetwebstack"-project:
https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/

I haven't tried MemFlex, but it looks nice - for now I'm using SimpleMembership